# How to install the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) on Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide, gsl

I'm trying to install `gem 'gsl'` in Cloud9 IDE. But it requires that the GSL library (https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) already be installed.

**Error:**

```
missing required library to compile this module
```

**Documentation:**

> Note that the GSL libraries must already be installed before Ruby/GSL
>   can be installed:

Source: https://github.com/SciRuby/rb-gsl

I've been searching and have seen some recommended solution for installing on Windows, and Heroku (via buildpacks), but no solutions for an IDE like Cloud9.

To be honest I'm completely lost here and was wondering if anyone else has experience doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `rb-gsl` [documentation](https://github.com/SciRuby/rb-gsl) you linked to, you need to install:

`libgsl0-dev`

on the Cloud9 workspace, since Cloud9 workspaces are running Ubuntu 14.04.

In order to do that, you can do:

`sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev`

and then try installing the gem.